# How to prevent page refresh or default prompt box in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

In my Quiz application have 10 questions in a page and all are input controls, I enter required answer, during the time refresh a page without submitting, the browser gives a below pop up.

Solution:

I want an customize pop up (instead of Chrome pop up) to say you need to finish all the quiz and submit,
or disable the refresh.

How to do  that, is there any better solution?

[image]

Comment: No, you can't force the user to stay on the page. At most you can prompt user to confirm page leave/reload.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent page refresh, listen the beforeunload event of the window object and call for the preventDefault method of the event argument.

reference https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Do something
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: is it possible to do custom pop up box or bootstrap dialog in before unload

Comment: sure you can, put your code inside of callback for that